# Disable Knime Node feature (unable to disable via configuration)

Tags: configuration, knime

I'm new to knime, and I'm attempting to recreate this* OpenMS mass spectrometry workflow as an OpenMS-Knime workflow. The OpenMS workflow was originally performed manually at the OpenMS command line.

The bump I'm running into now is, the paper states ...

> [OpenMS **PeakPickerHiRes** was used to calculate] centroids of peaks from
>   profile mass spectra, with **signal-to-noise filter disabled**...

So, the Knime implementation of OpenMS has the correct PeakPickerRes node, with all the correct configuration parameters. However, the algorithm filter does not appear to have the option of simply being 'disabled'. It has configuration items that, perhaps, can be set to render it more-or-less non-functional, but **I'm wondering if there's a way to manually edit the node (via code or another method) to entirely disable the feature.**

[image: Knime node configuration window]

- Zhang et al. 2014 - DeMix Workflow for Efficient Identification of Co-fragmented Peptides in High Resolution Data-dependent Tandem Mass Spectrometry

Comment: It is not clear for me what is your problem... The documentation states `0.0 disables SNT estimation`, which as I understand means you can "manually" disable the signal to noise filter/estimation (the signal to noise ratio is always non-negative, so if the minimum is `0.0`, it means nothing is filtered out, filtering is disabled practically).

Comment: Hi Gabor. That was my assumption, but I wasn't sure if it was effective in removing all filtering. (I changed it to 0 as a test, and didn't quite get the same results as Dr. Bo's sample data I was comparing against.) According to Dr. Bo, whose paper I was quoting, the older version of OpenMS had a command line switch to simply disable filtering. I can't confirm that however, and it no longer seems to be an option.